# use multi dimensional array outside loop scope in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, scope

i want to use arrData array outside loop too, how to declare it outside loops scope, as if now it is not being populated correctly

```
  $SQL = "SELECT * FROM DailyData WHERE User='$_SESSION[userID]'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($SQL); 
    $i=0; 
    // trying this
    $arrData= array();
    $arrData []= array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
    echo $row['Score'] . " " . $row['Date']; 
    $arrData[i][1]=$row['Date']; 
    $arrData[i][2]=$row['Score']; 
    $i++; 
    echo "<br />"; 
    }
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, it appears that your variable $arrData is residing within the outer scope of the while-loop.. so this code should be golden

Comment: but how to properly declare it outside loop's scope, because it is not getting populated right

Comment: Just use $arrData = array();
You dont need the $arrdata [] = array(); when youŕe in the loop and specify the $arrData[i][x], it will automagically create an array on i for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this may be what you're looking for:

```
  $SQL = "SELECT * FROM DailyData WHERE User='$_SESSION[userID]'"; 
  $result = mysql_query($SQL); 
  $arrData= array();

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  { 
    $arrData[]=$row;
    //you can also do some output here if you want
  }

  //arrData is now available outside the while-loop
  foreach($arrData as $row) {
    echo $row['Score'] . ' ' . $row['Date'] . '<br />'; 
  }
```

Comment: What you are doing here is exactly the same as $arrData = mysql_fetch_array($result); btw :p

Answer (score 2):

`$arrData` is available outside the scope of the `while` loop.

Looks like you forgot the dollar sign:

```
$arrData[i][1]=$row['Date']; 
$arrData[i][2]=$row['Score'];
```

Should be

```
$arrData[$i][1]=$row['Date']; 
$arrData[$i][2]=$row['Score'];
```

In the original, PHP thinks you mean `$arrData['i']`, which means you keep over writing `$arrData['i'][1]` and `$arrData['i'][2]` - however, you are incrementing `$i`, so you want to to make use of that variable - `$arrData[$i][1]` and `$arrData[$i][2]`.